# core.typed + datomic = No reader function for tag id

Tags: clojure, datomic, clojure-core.typed

I'm just getting started with clojure and core.typed, and keep running into the following error when I evaluate `(check-ns 'stocks.db)` with the following code:

```
(ns stocks.db
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.core.typed :refer [ann HMap]]))

(use '[datomic.api :only [q db] :as d])

(ann break-me [String -> (HMap)])
(defn break-me
  "Do I break cored.typed?"
  []
  {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]})
```

> ExceptionInfo No reader function for tag id  clojure.core/ex-info (core.clj:4327)

`(break-me)` evaluates to `{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db -1000000]}` as you'd expect.

Similarly to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373486/no-reader-function-error-using-datomic-in-light-table), the offending term is definitely `#db/id`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This works fine for me (no Exception). Are you using LightTable as in the other question? If so, maybe see: https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/244 and https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/376

Comment: No, I'm just running `lein repl` with Clojure 1.5.1 and Leiningen 2.3.4. Note it compiles and runs fine, only gives an error when evaluating `(check-ns 'stocks.db)`.

Comment: I've posted an answer to just the data readers part of the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829275/clojure-runtimeexception-no-reader-function-for-tag-db-id/45829276#45829276

Answer (score 4):

I'm new to Clojure and Datomic but, I think you need to generate your temporary id with the `tempid` function that's part of the Datomic API (see http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/index.html#datomic.api/tempid).

So it'd look like this:

```
(ns stocks.db
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.core.typed :refer [ann HMap]]))

(use '[datomic.api :only [q db] :as d])

(ann break-me [String -> (HMap)])
(defn break-me
  "Do I break cored.typed?"
  []
  {:db/id (tempid :db.part/db)})
```

I'm having similar issues with `clojure.edn/read-string`, I haven't quite figured it out.  Hope that works for you.

**UPDATE:**
In this code: https://github.com/Datomic/codeq/blob/master/src/datomic/codeq/core.clj the Datomic folks seem to be doing just what you are. So while in your case I think using `tempid` will work, I think there's a deeper issue, and it seems like it has to do with the literal `#db/id`.

**UPDATE:**
Here: https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic/blob/master/samples/literals_vs_code.clj using `tempid` rather than literals is recommended.

**UPDATE:**
I've found a solution that also resolves my issue. I was trying to read in my schema from a file: `schema.edn` using `clojure.edn/read-string` after reading the contents as a string using `clojure.core/slurp` and got similar error complaining about the `#db/id` literal.

I implemented the `read-all` and `transact-all` functions found here: https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic/blob/053b3bd983d165b8fa7c0c039712fb1cb75eddf3/src/datomic/samples/io.clj and it works fine.  It seems like there are some sneaky issues with using the reader to parse `#db/id` literals, still haven't figured out exactly why.

**UPDATE:**
This is using a Clojure feature called "tagged literals" which allows you to define a map of "data readers" in a file named `data_readers.clj` at the root of your classpath that should contain a map of tag names and vars that will parse the arguments to the tag.

So with this `data_readers.clj` file:

```
{minutes my.project/to-minutes
 seconds my.project/to-seconds}
```

You can do this:

```
#minutes 3
#seconds 4
```

You can read about tagged literals at the bottom of this page: http://clojure.org/reader.

However, I still have not figured out the reason for the issue with the `#db/id` tagged literal.  I've posted a question on the Clojure group forum here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/datomic/Fi7iXps2npw. **Update:** Ben Kamphaus provides a nice explanation there.

Comment: How would you specify an entry in a `data_readers.clj` file for `#db/id`? Something along the lines of `{id db/id}`?

Comment: @DavidShaked I'm not sure what you mean. There's already a reader macro for #db/id.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @DavidShaked you can see what it looks like in the datomic jar files `data_readers.clj` file, but it would be something like this: `{db/id datomic.db/id-literal}`. Note that the map format is the new tag symbol is the key, and the value is a function (or var pointing to a function) for the reader to call to read the literal.