# Clojure RuntimeException - No reader function for tag db/id

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, datomic, edn

What is happening when I get this error in Clojure?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No reader function for tag db/id
```

Answer (score 11):

### Tagged Literals

This error message is related to a feature introduced in Clojure 1.7,
[tagged literals](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#tagged_literals). Tagged literals are a simple means for extending
what data types can be represented as literals in Clojure code or [EDN](https://github.com/edn-format/edn)
data.

Clojure ships with readers for two tagged literals, `#inst` and
`#uuid` allowing literal representations of `java.util.Date` and
`java.util.UUID`. Support for more tags can be added by including
`data_readers.clj` files on the classpath as [described in the
documentation](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#tagged_literals).

### Common causes

Some common causes of this error:

- Trying to read Datomic transaction data containing `#db/id` literals
- While attempting to use the [EDN reader](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.edn-api.html#clojure.edn/read) without passing `:readers`
- In [Boot](http://boot-clj.com/) tasks that try to use the EDN reader by passing
  `*data-readers*`.

### Using the EDN reader

One common cause of this error is trying to use the [EDN reader](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.edn-api.html#clojure.edn/read)
without passing the `:readers` option. From the doc string for
`clojure.edn/read`:

```
:readers  - a map of tag symbols to data-reader functions to be
            considered before default-data-readers. When not
            supplied, only the default-data-readers will be used.
```

As its name implies, `default-data-readers` is *only* the map of data
readers that ship with Clojure itself. That is, it does not include
any readers defined in the `data_readers.clj` files of any libraries
you are using (like, say, Datomic). The solution in this case is to
pass the current set of loaded data readers, found in the var
`*data-readers*`.

```
(clojure.edn/read {:readers *data-readers*} <your-read-source>)
```

Or, even better, explicitly specify the mapping of the data readers
you want to use. For instance, if you want to be able to use only the
datomic data readers:

```
(require 'datomic.db
         'datomic.function
         'datomic.codec)

(edn/read {:readers {'db/id  datomic.db/id-literal
                     'db/fn  datomic.function/construct
                     'base64 datomic.codec/base-64-literal}}
          <your-read-source-here>)
```

And of course, since these are just clojure maps we're dealing with,
we could also include the `default-data-readers` by merging the maps:

```
(require 'datomic.db
         'datomic.function
         'datomic.codec)

(edn/read {:readers (merge
                     default-data-readers
                     {'db/id  datomic.db/id-literal
                      'db/fn  datomic.function/construct
                      'base64 datomic.codec/base-64-literal})}
          <your-read-source-here>)
```